# Find the options of the tkinter.PhotoImage using tkinter and Python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am learning Python and tkinter. To load a picture into tkinter,`Canvas`, we use `file='picture path'` in the `PhotoImage` as below.

```
 import tkinter as tk
 p=tk.PhotoImage(file=r'C:\\Users\\vijay\\Desktop\\dogs.gif')
```

My question is, where is option 'file' located in the `PhotoImage` class? Its not in `Image` class too.

To learn all these classes without constantly taking help from internet, I wish to find out myself. There might be other options which might be useful, but I will never know if I don't know how to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tkinter is a thin wrapper around a tcl interpreter with the tk library. The canonical documentation for tcl/tk can be found here: http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/contents.htm.

The official python documentation gives a brief overview of how to translate the tcl/tk documentation into python in a section named [Tkinter Live Preserver](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-life-preserver)

For most commands, translation into python is very straight forward. For example, for the `PhotoImage` class you can look at the photo man page which lists the options data, format, file, gamma, height, palette, and width.